# Canonical Answer to Data Recovery

Tags: discussion

With Sandy and some of the new questions popping up like this one:

[All servers flooded by salt water, is it possible to recover data from multi-platter drives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/447092/all-servers-flooded-by-salt-water-is-it-possible-to-recover-data-from-multi-pla)

It seems like we may want to setup a standard data recovery question that lists potential things to do in the event of a data recovery scenario.  By default all questions like this tend to solicit lots of debate and ideas as to what can be done.

Should we setup a new canonical answer regarding data recovery and then mark all others as duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would troll around for a good data recovery question that's already been thoroughly answered and make that one the canonical example.  We've answered the question more than once in the past

It gets a bit more complicated with Data Recovery as sometimes it's physical damage where other times it's accidental erasure, and the process for tape versus HD may be a little different (more you can try with tapes before shipping them off), so maybe something like the [Capacity Planning](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) question that then links to physical versus digital questions might be sensible...

Comment: @BrentPabst ...in fact the one you linked to is a good candidate to be canonized.

Comment: Agreed, can you change it over as such?  However, I do like @HopelessN00b's idea as well in terms of maybe converting the question into a more generic DR capacity.

Comment: A generic DR post is huge -- we can cover individual aspects like "how do I deal with my wrecked hard drives" Q&A style, but doing a generic DR post is really more blog territory than main site...

Comment: Yea, after thinking about it some more I agree.  I think the one brought up today covers the DR after a natural disaster scenario for HDD issues.

Comment: It looks like the question I mentioned has gotten a lot of community support. What is the canonization process?

Answer (score 3):

I've actually thought about this on and off for a while, and I think the better approach would be like what was done recently with the spam question - broaden it a bit to basically an `I lost a bunch of data, what do I do?` question.  That way we can hit the issue of taking backups in the first place, and leave actual data recovery techniques as the last or second-to-last resort they really ought to be.

I even thought about doing it `answer your own question Q&A style` after the last wave of `my RAID array crashed, what do I do?` questions, but I never got around to doing anything about it for some reason.

Anyway, I think that if one of the mods were to do like @ChrisS did with [the spam canonical](https://serverfault.com/questions/419407/fighting-spam-what-can-i-do-as-an-email-administrator-domain-owner-or-user), it would go over best.  I'd do it myself, but I'm not really sure if that's a good idea coming from just a user, or if it would get hammered for being a duplicate of the countless other questions out three or what have you, so I'm a bit gun-shy on it.